# WPF DataGrid Binding only works one-way

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I want to bind my DataGrid columns. First I create the columns in DataGrid:

```
translationDataGrid = new DataGrid
{
    IsReadOnly = true,
};
var fact = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(CheckBox));
fact.SetBinding(CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty, new Binding("Check") {Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay});
translationDataGrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTemplateColumn
{
    CellTemplate = new DataTemplate {VisualTree = fact}
});
translationDataGrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn
{
    Header = "Name",
    Binding = new Binding("Name"),
    Width = 250
});
```

Than I have a class which I use to create objects to add to DataGrid:

```
private class ObjectToDataGrid : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _check;

    public bool Check
    {
        get { return _check; }
        set
        {
            _check = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Check");
        }
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
    }
}
```

And here I add objects to DataGrid:

```
public void AddToDataGrid(string tag)
{
    translationDataGrid.Items.Add(
        new ObjectToDataGrid
        {
            Check = false,
            Name = tag,
        });
}
```

The problem is, that it only changes one-way. If I change the data, like this:

```
foreach (ObjectToDataGrid row in translationDataGrid.Items)
{
    row.Check = check;
}
```

data in grid change as they supposed to. But when I check the checkBox, and than try to retrieve Checked value from the underlying object, its unchanged.

I've been looking for a solution for several hours now, but I can't find it. Can someone please help?

Comment: is there any specific reason not to use `DataGridCheckBoxColumn`?

Comment: Yes, I didn't want to have to click twice to check it. [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e1858654-26bd-4050-a1be-1f5d0209b1fe/how-do-i-change-a-datagrid-checkbox-without-clicking-twice?forum=wpf)

Comment: Have you tried `IsReadonly = false` as per MSDN _If this property is set to true while the control is in editing mode, all pending edits are discarded._

Comment: Yes, it changes nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try set `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged`

```
new Binding("Check") { 
                       Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay , 
                       UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged 
                     }
```